# How to order an array/list of int that is received as a string by input in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I was trying to test my skills and I try to do a test.

I receive the following input:

[7,11,10,6,9]

[21,24,25,23,26]

[116,115,117,120,121,119]

I need to sort all these values.

I try to do the following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] parts = null;
List<String> linhas = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    line = line.replace("[","");
    line = line.replace("]","");
    line = line.replace(" ","");
    System.out.println(line);
    parts = line.split(",");
}
```

This way I got to show the output

7,11,10,6,9

21,24,25,23,26

116,115,117,120,121,119

The "String[parts]" got all values, but I don't know how to sort it, because the "parts" parameter is inside a "for loop".

How can I convert it to int/Integer and sort each line?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Consider using a loop in combination with `Integer.parseInt("string")`...Also you can look at `Arrays.sort()`...

Comment: If you want to keep the way you are doing it you can also use `line = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1);` to remove the brackets instead of replacing them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `[7,11,10,6,9]` be the input, we can try converting to a list of integers, and then sort that list:

```
String input = "[7,11,10,6,9]";
input = input.replaceAll("\\[(.*)\\]", "$1");
String[] vals = input.split(",");
List<Integer> output = Arrays.stream(vals)
    .map(v -> Integer.parseInt(v))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(output);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output.toArray()));
```

This prints:

```
[6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `parts` you must convert this `String[]` into an `int[]`. To do this, first create an int[] for your results to go in. It must be the same size as your `String[]`:

```
int[] ints = new int[parts.length];
```

Then, iterate through the `String[]` and fill in values in the `int[]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);  // converts a string containing an integer into its int value
}
```

Finally, to sort each line, a simple call to `Arrays.sort(ints);` will sort your array of integers.

Bonus:

This can be achieved more cleanly in a single line using Java 8 Streams, as follows:

```
List<Integer> sortedInts = Arrays.stream(parts).map(Integer::parseInt).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You are sorting Strings not ints. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Check this `int[] sortedInts = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"1", "2"}).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sorted().toArray();` Make `IntStream`, sort it, then invoke `toArray` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `replace()` lines at once and split more cleanly with a regex:

```
parts = line.split("[\\[\\], ]+");
```

and use the Iterable technique that cameron1024 demonstrates in his answer. I think that using `Iterable` is a better choice for this use case than using `Streams` because the input size is trivially small and `Streams` has to spend more time to spin up.

The whole thing would look like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] parts;
List<String> linhas = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    parts = line.split("[\\[\\] ,]+");
}

int ints[] = new int[parts.length];

for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(ints);
```

Comment: When I try to compile your code. The regex line gives me an error. Invalid escape sequence

Comment: It works now, but I need to change "int ints[parts.length];" to "int ints[] = new int[parts.length];"

Comment: Usually, I don't like to use regex. it is very confusing for me.